# Null output while storing tokenized output from StringTokenizer class nextToken() method in an array

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am trying to store the tokens obtained by using StringTokenizer class's nextToken() method. The tokens print fine when I print them. But when I try to store them in an array, they return null. I don't understand what is at play here. Could you please have a look and see what's happening here?

```
    import java.util.*;

    class TestSt{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String s = "My name is Sugandha";
            int len = 0, i=1;
            String[] ar  = new String[50];
            StringTokenizer s1 = new StringTokenizer(s," ");

            while(s1.hasMoreTokens()){
                ar[i] = s1.nextToken();
                i++;
                System.out.println(ar[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print the value after incrementing i , which means you are printing the next value which is unassigned yet and hence it will print null.

Also noticed you are saving values in the array from 1 index instead of 0, maybe you can fix that as well.

Here is a working code:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "My name is Sugandha";
        int i = 0;

        StringTokenizer s1 = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");

        String[] ar = new String[s1.countTokens()];

        while (s1.hasMoreTokens()) {
            ar[i++] = s1.nextToken();
        }

        for(int j= 0 ;j<ar.length;j++){
            System.out.println(ar[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed my mistake. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. It's sorted now.

Comment: @SUGANDHARUCHIR , You can accept the answer in case it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

use the below code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "My name is Sugandha";
    int len = 0, i = 1;
    String[] ar = new String[50];
    StringTokenizer s1 = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");

    while (s1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        ar[i] = s1.nextToken();
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
        i++; // this line is moved, print and increment
    }
}
```